# Equivalent to raw_input in Kiwi?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input, kiwi

I have some experience with Python but I'm new to Kiwi.
Can someone please provide me an example of a code for a program in which the user gives an input (like in Python's "raw_input") and after pressing a button the program prints a response using the provided input? 
A program which adds the number 1 to an input will do.

This is actually very important to me.
Thanks!